# Inclusion in sequences of theories and models

Tags: model-theory

Is this theorem true, and if so does it have a name and where can I reference it?

"Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be theories where $T_1 \subset T_2$. If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are the classes of all models of $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively, then $K_1 \supseteq K_2$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $T_1 \subseteq T_2 \Rightarrow K_1 \supseteq K_2$ follows almost immediately from the definition of what it is to be a model of a theory: to say that $T_1 \subseteq T_2$ means that $T_2$ requires at least as many things to be true than $T_1$ does. This means that a model of $T_2$ is automatically a model of $T_1$, so that $K_2 \subseteq K_1$.

Comment: Is this variant any harder to prove: $T_2 \turnstile T_1 \implies K_1 \supseteq K_2$? I'm looking for a reference because I want to include this in an argument being made to Computer Scientists, some of whom have no background in Model Theory.

Comment: The argument is more or less the same when you spell out the details. If $T_2 \vdash T_1$, that is $T_2 \vdash \varphi$ for all $\varphi \in T_1$, and $M \vDash T_2$, then certainly $M \vDash T_1$ because $M$ makes everything true that $T_2$ believes to be true (in particular, all the axioms of $T_1$).